# How to left -align navbar-text?

Tags: twitter, twitter-bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4-beta

I am attempting to build a small page with BS4 (beta2).

```
<nav id="TOP" class="navbar navbar-light">
<span id="banner-logo" class="navbar-brand">
<span class="fa fa-bath fa-5x"></span>
</span>
<span id="banner-heading" class="navbar-text"><h1>
Wonderful page-title
</h1>
</span>
</nav>
```

(There also is a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mbaas/0wh6ond3/))

Somehow I am missing something in the construction of the nav: I'd like to the `#banner-heading`-element to be left-aligned, next to the icon. Why is that not working?

**EDIT**: I noticed that it works if I put the nav into a  - but the BS-Examples all do not do that, so something else must be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't work much with bootstrap 4 beta before but I don't believe you are doing it right, just took a quick look at the documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/),

Navbar are formatted like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
   <span class="fa fa-bath fa-3x"></span>
   Wonderful page-title
 </a>
</nav>
```

And you can but your menu and content in a container.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      My little menu
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      Main content area, 9 cols wide
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akassama/2w8z4efr/)

**EDIT**

To @Mbaas's comment, if you want the icon to be the link and not the text, use li and put the anchor tags around the icon.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <li class="navbar-brand">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="fa fa-bath fa-3x"></span> 
    </a>
      Wonderful page-title
  </li>
</nav>
```

You can remove the underline hover of the link by applying css like:

```
.navbar-brand a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

To make the text large as a h1 tag you can put it in a span with a class and apply css to it like:

```
 <span class="bold-text">
      Wonderful page-title
 </span>
```

And the css for `bold-text` could be something like:

```
.bold-text{
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size: 40px;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akassama/gammpbze/1/)

Comment: Yea, but what if I only wanted to link the icon, but not the page-title? As soon as I take "Wonderful page title" out of the `a`-tag, I have the same problem again!

Comment: Yes, that worked. But in my question I had that title in an `h1`-tag...and that destroys the formatting again! :( Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mbaas/utfv82u6/

Comment: @MBaas Ok, you can put the text in a span and apply css to that span. See my updated answer :-)